# SQL query to show minimum average along with title using two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
huffman_students (
id (PK),
fname,
lname,
status ("freshman", "sophomore", "junior", "senior"),
majorcode (FK - huffman_departments.deptcode),
gpa,
admittedDate)

huffman_departments (
deptcode (PK),
deptname,
college)
```

I need to show the college the lowest average GPA.

I have been able to come up with this query:

```
SELECT MIN(avg_gpa)
FROM
(
SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa)
FROM huffman_departments d, huffman_students s
WHERE s.majorcode = d.deptcode
GROUP BY d.college
);
```

Which gives the output:

```
MIN(AVG_GPA)
------------
       3.436
```

I need output that looks like:

```
COLLEGE    MIN(AVG_GPA)
-----------------------
INF               3.436
```

I have tried a lot of different queries and keep getting errors. A common error that I am getting when trying to show the college that lowest average gpa belongs to is: "not a single-group group function."

I am using Oracle SQL Plus.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Try adding the College to your outer query

Comment: Your inner query only returns 1 row per college.  What's the point of your outer query?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the existing query to a subquery (or a CTE), and then use analytic function ROW_NUMBER to filter the relevant record :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) avg_spa
    FROM 
        huffman_departments d
        INNER JOIN huffman_students s ON s.majorcode = d.deptcode
    GROUP BY d.college
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY avg_spa) rn
    FROM cte c
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

PS : always use explicit JOINs instead of implicit (CROSS JOIN + WHERE clause). I changed the query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Common Table Expressions

```
with cte0 as 
(
  SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) agpa
  FROM huffman_departments d, huffman_students s
  WHERE s.majorcode = d.deptcode
  GROUP BY d.college
)
select * from cte0  c
where c.college (
  select ci.college from cte0 ci
  group by ci.college 
  having min(ci.agpa) = a.gpa
)
```

if you are using mysql

```
SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa)
FROM huffman_departments d, huffman_students s
WHERE s.majorcode = d.deptcode
GROUP BY d.college
order by 2 asc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

If you are looking for one row, you can use `ORDER BY` and `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`:

```
SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa)
FROM huffman_departments d JOIN
     huffman_students s
     ON s.majorcode = d.deptcode
GROUP BY d.college
ORDER BY AVG(s.gpa)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

If you want to see multiple rows in the event of ties, there are multiple approaches.  In MySQL 8+, window functions are probably the simplest method.  In earlier versions, double aggregation may be the simplest:

```
SELECT avg_gpa, LISTAGG(college, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY college) as colleges
FROM (SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) as avg_gpa
      FROM huffman_departments d JOIN
           huffman_students s
           ON s.majorcode = d.deptcode
      GROUP BY d.college
     ) c
ORDER BY avg_gpa
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

EDIT:

Older versions of Oracle do not support `FETCH FIRST`.  So you can do:

```
SELECT college, avg_gpa
FROM (SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) as avg_gpa,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(s.gpa)) as seqnum
      FROM huffman_departments d JOIN
           huffman_students s
           ON s.majorcode = d.deptcode
      GROUP BY d.college
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY AVG(s.gpa);
```

Comment: First one: "error at line 7: sql command not properly ended."

Comment: Second one: "error at line 9: sql command not properly ended."

Answer (score 0):

Using what you already have:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM  (SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) avg_gpa
FROM huffman_departments d, huffman_students s
WHERE s.majorcode = d.deptcode
GROUP BY d.college
) b
WHERE b.avg_gpa = (SELECT MIN(a.avg_gpa)
FROM
(
SELECT d.college, AVG(s.gpa) avg_gpa
FROM huffman_departments d, huffman_students s
WHERE s.majorcode = d.deptcode
GROUP BY d.college
) a);
```

Comment: Error at line 5: invalid identifier. 

I changed the avg_salary to avg_gpa. Neither one worked.

Comment: I found a query that ended up working. I will try to post it tomorrow after I get my laptop out again. Thank for the help. I will try your updated query tomorrow, too.